# Eclipse Neon with JDK 7 or below

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, compilation

When I compile / run the build on ant with eclipse neon on JDK 7 and below I got error message saying `Unsupported must run on 1.8 or higher`. If I changed my ant and jdk to 8 on ant I got `unsupported minior/major version`....

Is there a way to build with jdk 7 and below with eclipse neon? if I made this upgrade am I sacrificing all my previous changes and development?

Comment: check your build.xml, you must have defined jdk version 1.8 but jdk on your system is lower than 1.8

Comment: Not sure what is wrong in your setup; but I have a 1.7 and a 1.8 JDK defined within my preferences for eclipse-neon; and depending on some context; stuff gets build for either of them; without any problems. As Boola says; I guess there is one part of your system that says "I need 1.8", and you are only "giving" that component the 1.7 JDK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eclipse Neon itself must be run using Java 8.

You can still use older Java versions to run your programs. Configure the available JRE/JDKs in the Preferences in 'Java > Installed JREs'. Then configure your project or Run Configuration to choose the version you want to use.

Comment: but with this wont you run into unsupported minor/major version 53.0?

Comment: Not if you configure your project's JDK Compliance settings properly in the Project 'Java Compiler' settings.

Comment: It seems I still got the error but it was fixed after I adjusted my class path system environment variable to the compliance level to be the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit like this following(make sure with your installation path),

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin 
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally Neon should be run on java 1.8 but you can run neon on java 1.7

just change the java version in eclipse.ini file.
Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7

Comment: that's gonna give you a an error , it gave me an error